# WinSCP is auto hide folders with (.) prefix

Tags: winscp, hidden-file

When I upload folders beginning with (.) such as (.dart_tool) to the server through WinSCP, they automatically got hidden.

I don't want them to be hidden in the server.

How can I Prevent the program from doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS is on the server? dot-files are automatically hidden by unix-style OSes, intentionally.

Comment: Actually I'm backing up files to my (Samsung Secure Folder) with Android Oreo. Is there a way to prevent android from auto hide folders?

Comment: When I connect e.g. to an RaspbianOS using WinSCP in SFTP mode I see all files and folders starting with a `.`.

Comment: So do you want to see them in WinSCP or on Android? Your title suggests the WinSCP.

Comment: I just want them not to be converted to hidden files, so I can see them on PC in case I copied them back to it from Android.

Comment: there is no conversion involved, hidden is not an attribute in *nix. the directories are not altered in any way. its just that all the shell apps don't display items that start with `.` unless the shell is configured to do so. See here for the kinds of file attrib available in linux: https://linoxide.com/how-tos/howto-show-file-attributes-in-linux/ So what kind of PC did you want to see them on? windows? windows doesn't hide .files automatically. for Gnome GUI windows on whatever distro, hit Ctrl+h to toggle display of hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the folder had become hidden in a way that would make me see it hidden also on Windows, but I have now tried copying the folder from Android to Windows and found the folder visible.

Thanks to everyone who helped me and explained the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All files that start with `.` are treated as hidden on *nix shells. WinSCP assumes that the remote server is *nix, so it by default hides such files on the remote panel.

You can make WinsCP display all files in preferences using the [*Show hidden files* option](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_panels#common).